# Styled-components packages doesn't seem to work: _styledComponents.default.h1 is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, styled-components

I've implemented just a basic example from the styled-components website.

The error I get in my iOS emulator is:
_styledComponents.default.h1 is not a function. (In _styledComponents.default.h1(_template,plateObject())','_syledComponents.default.h1' is undefined))

I'm guessing there's a problem with the styled-components npm installation. It did warn me about missing peer dependencies. Which goes something like this:

```
npm WARN react-native@0.57.1 requires a peer of react@16.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

When I try another example, like making a simple button, I get a similar error. Any ideas of something that I might be missing? Or things I ought to try?

Here's the code:

```
// Create a Title component that'll render an <h1> tag with some styles
const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: palevioletred;
`;

 // Create a Wrapper component that'll render a <section> tag with some styles
const Wrapper = styled.section`
  padding: 4em;
  background: papayawhip;
`;
```

Comment: Are you trying to use `html` tags in `react-native` ?

Comment: I'm just testing styled-components by pasting one of the examples of their website in my code. The same thing happens when I make a simple styled-components button

Comment: The example that you're using does not work in `react-native`. Use this [example](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#react-native)

Comment: That's it. I've got a lot to learn still. Thank you for your help!